# Row Level Security on Shared data set SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssas

I'm looking for a way to filter the data to employees something like create a "user to Client relationship", the problem is this is after the fact,I have 100+reports that already exist and I don't want to edit each one, I use a shard Data source, can i somehow implement RLS on that source ? or maybe use ssas RLS in conjunction.

SQL server 2012 enterprise,

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution which comes to my mind is to add to each shared dataset a part which will filter rows based on domain user name.

This will require that:

1. User running SSRS report will have to have access to SQL Server
2. You would have to build tables to define access right (if you do not have already)

If you would be running SQL Server 2014 and onwards you could use built in RLS. You would have to define access right and create access control function. Still you have to have some kind of data store which will help you to determine what is visible to each user - more details on RLS [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn765131.aspx).

Comment: do you mean data set or source, they all have completely different data sets, the same source just a connection string to a single Database,  my issue is i don't want to edit each set, i could potentially add a hidden parameter but still would likely have to edit the queries that drive the report, thats what im trying to avoid

Comment: Well without changing datasets either way you wouldn't be able to implement RLS (unless you switch to 2014 or 2016) You could move queries to stored procedures and do it there as well, but still you cannot avoid the change.